# Duplicate foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two POCO entities, ApplicationUser and Account.

- One Account has many ApplicationUsers.
- Each account has exactly one ApplicationUser who is the BillingContact

So, my entities are:

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BillingContact")]
    public string BillingContactId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser BillingContact { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
```

My problem is that when I create a migration, code-first only partially understands that BillingContact is a foreign key.  The migration code creates the Account table with the BillingContactId foreign key, but it also creates an extra Account_Id foreign key field.

I've found a workaround, but it seriously doesn't pass the "smell" test.  The underlying problem is that I have multiple relationships between the two classes, which confuses code-first. In particular, the ApplicationUser entity does not have a navigation property that is the "other end" of the BillingContact foreign key.

If I add a navigation property to ApplicationUser, and mark it with the InverseProperty attribute then code-first seems to understand the foreign key and doesn't create the extra field:

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("BillingContact")]
    public virtual ICollection<Account> MyBillingAccounts { get; set; }
}
```

The problem with this workaround is that the MyBillingAccounts navigation property is totally bogus. An Account has a related ApplicationUser that is the billing contact, but reverse relationship (navigating from an ApplicationUser back to the BillingContactId foreign key) makes no actual sense.

So... **Is there a better (or proper) way to teach code-first about the BillingContactId foreign key?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only do this with fluent mapping. For example in an override of `OnModelCreating` of your context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
            .HasOptional(acc => acc.BillingContact)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(acc => acc.BillingContactId);
```

The empty `WithMany()` call indicates that there is an inverse end of the association without a navigation property.

Comment: Thanks for the instant answer!  Actually, I think I need `HasRequired()` rather than `HasOptional()` because I want the FK to be required (not nullable).  But that detail wasn't clear in the OP.